# UITableView appears on iOS 7.1 but does not appear on iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`I use Xcode 6.2, and swift and this particular class with which I am having issue is in ObjectiveC. I am using storyboard, a tabcontroller, and one of the tabs calls the`historyViewController` which has a table view. In iOS7, when I click on the history tabBarButton, the table view appears with its data.

In iOS8, when I click on history tabBarButton, the table view doesn't appear. If I click on some other tabBarButton, and then again select the history tabBarButton, the table view properly appears with its data.

```
#import "historyListViewController.h"
#import "QRdatabase.h"
#import "qrdbinfo.h"
#import "historyDetailViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
@implementation historyListViewController
@synthesize details = _details;
@synthesize qrInfos = _qrInfos;
@synthesize segmentchange;

- (IBAction)valid_in_seg:(id)sender
{
if (segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{   self.qrInfos = [QRdatabase database].qrdbInfos;
[self.tablelist reloadData];

}
else
{
self.qrInfos = [QRdatabase database].inqrdbInfos;

}
[self.tablelist reloadData];

}
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

 // Scroll table view to the last row
 if (_shouldScrollToLastRow)
 {
    _shouldScrollToLastRow = NO;
    [self.tablelist setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
 }
 [self.tablelist reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.tablelist reloadData];
   UIImage *myImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_white_38.png"];
  UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 38, 38)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = myImageView;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
segmentchange.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

_shouldScrollToLastRow = YES;

if (segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    self.qrInfos = [QRdatabase database].qrdbInfos;

    [self.tablelist reloadData];

}
else
{
    self.qrInfos = [QRdatabase database].inqrdbInfos;
    [self.tablelist reloadData];
}
self.tablelist.delegate = self;
self.tablelist.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tablelist];


}
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 if (segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
 {
     self.qrInfos = [QRdatabase database].qrdbInfos;
     [self.tablelist reloadData];

 }
 else
 {
     self.qrInfos = [QRdatabase database].inqrdbInfos;
     [self.tablelist reloadData];
 }

 [self.tablelist reloadData];
 }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

}

/*- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.qrInfos = nil;
  self.details = nil;
 }*/


#pragma mark Table view methods
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ if (segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{

return 80;
}
else
    return 120;

}


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
 }


// Customize the number of rows in the table view
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [_qrInfos count];
}


 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  if (segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tablelist dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
    qrdbinfo *info = [_qrInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = info.qr_code;

 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date:  %@", info.date];

    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:info.img]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_not_available.png"]];
    return cell;

 }
 else
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tablelist dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    qrdbinfo *info = [_qrInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.textLabel.text = info.qr_code;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date:  %@", info.date];
    return cell;

  }
 // return cell;
  }

  - (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
  {
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,    NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if ( !error )
                           {
                               UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                               completionBlock(YES,image);
                           } else{
                               completionBlock(NO,nil);
                           }
                       }];
 }


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
qrdbinfo *info = [_qrInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                              bundle:nil];
historyDetailViewController * vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];

   vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
vc.qrId = info.uniqueId;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alerts = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Data Unavailable" message:@"No data available for invalid scans" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil, nil];

    [alerts show];
}
               }



 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 qrdbinfo *info = [_qrInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.qrInfos removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.tablelist deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

 if(segmentchange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
 {
 // Delete the row from the data source

 [[QRdatabase database] deleterow:info.uniqueId];


 }
 else
 {
     [[QRdatabase database] deleteinvalidrow:info.uniqueId];
 }
 [self.tablelist reloadData ];

 }
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }


@end
```

Comment: 404: no question found. 404: no code found.

Comment: Post your code. It will be more help full to solve your problem.

Comment: ... and some screenshots would help.  (Btw, do you have Constraints set on your controls in the Storyboard...?)

Comment: To debug these type of things, try setting a border around the view. Another thing you can try is using the Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy. Then you can see what views are on your screen.

Comment: i added the code too@RajeshMaurya,

Comment: @MikeGledhill , I have constraints set on the controls., but it works fine on iPhone 4.(iOS 7)

Comment: @BlackMagic, thank you for introducing this new debugging way, I will try to resolve problems using it ,  am new to iOS development.

Comment: Have you set the tableview delegate and datasource correctly in the storyboard